# RCov doesn't work

Tags: ruby, metrics, rcov, metric-fu

I am currently developing a Ruby gem and want to create metrics.

I am using 'metric_fu', but RCov seems to leave my specs.

Here is my metric_fu configuration:

```
MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|
        config.metrics  = [:churn, :saikuro, :flog, :flay, :reek, :roodi, :rcov]
        config.graphs   = [:flog, :flay, :reek, :roodi, :rcov]
        config.flay     = { :dirs_to_flay => ['lib']  } 
        config.flog     = { :dirs_to_flog => ['lib']  }
        config.reek     = { :dirs_to_reek => ['lib']  }
        config.roodi    = { :dirs_to_roodi => ['lib'] }
        config.saikuro  = { :output_directory => 'scratch_directory/saikuro', 
                            :input_directory => ['lib'],
                            :cyclo => "",
                            :filter_cyclo => "0",
                            :warn_cyclo => "5",
                            :error_cyclo => "7",
                            :formater => "text"} #this needs to be set to "text"
        config.churn    = { :start_date => "1 year ago", :minimum_churn_count => 10}
        config.rcov     = { :test_files => ["spec/**/*_spec.rb"],
                            :rcov_opts => ["--sort coverage", 
                                           "--no-html", 
                                           "--text-coverage",
                                           "--no-color",
                                           "--profile",
                                           "--spec-only",
                                           "--exclude /gems/,/Library/,spec"]}
end
```

Do you have some tips?

Best regards

Comment: Which version of "metric_fu" are you running?
Have you done "config.gem" stuff in your environment file?
In your Rake file, did you add "require 'metric_fu'"?

Comment: What's the error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is going to be hard to diagnose without a stack trace but I would suggest changing your config to this:

```
MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|
        config.metrics  = [:rcov]
        config.graphs   = [:rcov]
        config.rcov     = { :test_files => ["spec/**/*_spec.rb"],
                            :rcov_opts => ["--sort coverage", 
                                           "--no-html", 
                                           "--text-coverage",
                                           "--no-color",
                                           "--profile",
                                           "--spec-only",
                                           "--exclude /gems/,/Library/,spec"]}
end
```

So you can isolate the problem. Then run 'rake metrics:all --trace' and if you can't figure it out from there, post the results either here or the metric_fu google group: http://groups.google.com/group/metric_fu

You can also try running rcov straight from the command line (which is essentially what metric_fu does).

Hope that helps.